# Make Flex List Scroll To Bottom

Tags: apache-flex, list, actionscript, scroll, components

I have a Flex Spark List which can be populated with any number of rows. Each row can have a variable height with a minimum of 50px. I need a way to scroll to the "true" bottom. By true I mean the end of the last row. Since I'm new to AS and Flex, implementation & use code would be appreciated if anything advanced is needed (e.g extending classes etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your list is done rendering, you can try:

```
yourList.layout.verticalScrollPosition += yourList.layout.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(NavigationUnit.END);
```

there's a blog post about it here: http://flexponential.com/2011/02/13/scrolling-to-the-bottom-of-a-spark-list/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A small problem though: `cqlist.layout.verticalScrollPosition += cqlist.layout.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(NavigationUnit.END);` gives `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`. Always assuming latest versions.

Comment: To help, I'd need to see how you're calling this code. My test case works: `var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection()
    ac.addItem("Adam");
    ac.addItem("Bob");
    ac.addItem("Charlie");
    ac.addItem("Adam");
    ac.addItem("Charlie");
    ac.addItem("Dave");
    myList.dataProvider = ac;
    myList.validateNow();    myList.layout.verticalScrollPosition+=myList.layout.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(NavigationUnit.END);` I don't usually recommend validateNow(), but because of the issues with this property it seems necessary.